# Access an object attribute from the Hashmap

Tags: java, hashmap

I'm currently creating a simple taxi dispatch system for a java assignment.

the Taxi class contains the attribute platenumber.

I must have to create a hashmap that takes an area as a key and an ArrayList of taxi as the value. There are 6 different areas, and 50 unique Taxis(platenumber is what make them unique). each different area(key) is supposed to have a unique set of plates(or Taxis). and all areas are not to have more than 50 plates combined.

Now for my question,

Is there a way that I can access the object attribute (taxi plate number) within the the arraylist of taxi objects that is in the areas hashmap.

so,

```
areas.values()
```

will return my arraylist of Taxis

however I would like to get the plate number of the taxi objects that is in the taxi array list which is in the areas hashmap.

is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

> *Is there a way that I can access the object attribute (taxi plate number) within the the arraylist of taxi objects that is in the areas hashmap.*

Sure. To print the plate numbers for all taxis in a certain area, you would do:

```
List<Taxi> taxiesInArea = yourHashMap.get(area);

for (Taxi taxi : taxiesInArea)
    System.out.println(taxi.plateNumber());
```